ActiveRecord query for has_many :through with Enum
I have a simple has_many through: table
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  enum :status, [:inactive, :active]
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

This finds all memberships at a location that are active
Location.first.memberships.active

Is there a clean way to find all users at a location that are active? This does not work
Location.first.users.active


First solution with simple query is
User
  .joins(:memberships)
  .where(memberships: { location_id: location_id, status: 'active' })

Second solution with Location model modification is
has_many :active_memberships, -> { Membership.active }
has_many :active_users, through: :active_memberships, source: :user

# and then
Location.first.active_users

